# Creating a SoftLayer user profile ignores username field

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a user profile with the username cu-jmanweiler@us.ibm.com using REST API. The API is with POST and URL

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer.json
```

The json payload is:

```
    {
"parameters" : [
{
"address1" : "2455 South Road",
"city" : "Poughkeepsie",
"companyName" : "IBM Research",
"state" : "NY",
"country" : "US",
"postalCode" : "12601",
"firstName" : "Justin",
"lastName" : "Manweiler",
"email" : "rismadm@us.ibm.com",
"permissionSystemVersion" : "1",
"timezoneId" : "117",
"username" : "cu-jmanweiler@us.ibm.com",
"secondaryPasswordTimeoutDays" : 90,
"userStatusId" : 1001
},
"IBMcl0ud!",
"IBMcl0ud!"
]
}
```

> The user profile is created as id 6485555, but the username in the
>   profile is: 286900_rismadm@us.ibm.com

This is not the username I specified on the create of the user profile. It is critical that the user profile be created with the username specified. We use the username in the profile to indicate the type of user profile it is with a specific prefix. Please create the user profile with the username I specified. These profiles do not represent an IBMid in any way.
I also noticed that the username field has been removed from the SoftLayer portal panel when adding a user. This will break our management of Bare Metal and VMs in this account. Please do not assume all user profiles require an IBMid!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

this is because they are linking IBM blumix with softlayer now you cannot specify the any value in username, You can submit a ticket and complain to softlayer about that (they might give you a solution), but I do not think it is going to change.

Regards

Comment: My goodness, There was a major assumption that all SoftLayer user profiles were interactive,  What ever happened implementing major changes like this and maintaining backward compatibility?  I was told by SofgtLayer to write this problem report here as the SoftLayer API team hangs out here.  I tried using this flag managedByOIDCFlag but is said the flag is not known. I also tried usig flag managedByOpenIdConnectFlag set to false, but that was ignored also. ok, What is the username set to now in this incredible design that has broken our use of SoftLayer user profiles?

Comment: I am soorry but there is no way to set the username you want using API (the new design is like that), your username is always going to be 
"$yourAccountID_$usermail".

Comment: so I see this message 'Account 286900 is authenticated by IBMid,". What does that specifically mean for this account?  what will the username be now when I create a user profile.   The ticket in SoftLayer says "Unfortunately stack overflow will be your best bet with finding the more up to date information for the username prefix.".  They have basically walked away from any REST API questions, so here I am on stac kobverflow trying to understand some detail on this marvelousd change.

Comment: IBMid is used as a consistent way to access IBM products. you will use IBMid instead of your SoftLayer credentials to access all of SoftLayer's existing features and capabilities in the customer portal. In addition, you will have the option to use Bluemix-based IBM platform services and applications. By default, the email address you have associated with your SoftLayer account will be used for your IBMid. So your account can   access to the IBM products now. If you want to know more about IBMid the tickets that you submit must not be related to API.

Comment: As I answered you the new user that you create, always will be contain as username  your account ID and then it will contain the email that you set for that new user "$yourAccountID_$usermail"

Comment: Thank you for the answers.   will the username in the existing softLayer user profiles be changed to the new format "$yourAccountID_$usermail" ?

Comment: Ihave another question.  After the new SoftLayer user profile has been created.  Can I change the email address in the SoftLayer user profile? We change the email on these non interactive Softlayer user profiles to initiate a password change.

Comment: When the user logs in the portal a propmt windows ask if you want to change to IBMid if you the user selects to change, the next time that he logs to the control portal he will use his email to log in, but his username will not change. Yes you can change the email, but the username will not change it will remains with its original value.

Comment: Thank you.  sorry, but this change is very traumatic cfor us.